# Stripe Charge - get Stripe's processing fee amount on the transaction

Tags: .net, .net-core, stripe-payments

I'm looking for a way to get actual Stripe's processing fee from the API. It's typically **2.9% + 30c**. I can get it from the dashboard but I don't see any way to retrieve it from the charge API (or other APIs).

```
var charge = await chargeService.GetAsync(
    invoice.StripeChargeId, 
    requestOptions: new RequestOptions
{
    StripeAccount = account.StripeAccountId
});

charge.// stripe fees? 404
```

Note: I don't use Checkout Session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe processing fee for a particular Charge lives on the Balance Transaction object. You can find it under `balance_transaction` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-balance_transaction) on the Charge, and then look at `fee` and `fee_details` [properties](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/object#balance_transaction_object-fee_details). You can [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects?lang=dotnet) the `balance_transaction` property when retrieving a Charge.

In your case:

```
var options = new ChargeGetOptions();
options.AddExpand("balance_transaction");

var charge = await chargeService.GetSync(
    invoice.StripeChargeId,
    options,
    requestOptions: new RequestOptions {
        StripeAccount = account.StripeAccountId
    }
);

var feeDetails = charge.BalanceTransaction.FeeDetails;
```